# what's the difference between rawurldecode() and rawurldecode(urlencode(urldecode()))

Tags: php, urldecode

I have received a get request which contains a parameter like "aaa+bbb", I will

get "aaa bbb" with

```
rawurldecode("aaa+bbb")
```

but "aaa+bbb" with

```
rawurldecode(urlencode(urldecode("aaa+bbb")))
```

I don't understand it, what's the difference between rawurldecode() and

rawurldecode(urlencode(urldecode()))??

thank you

Comment: the urlencode function replaces all spaces with a '+' sign

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem — https://i.imgur.com/Vfhk8TH.png — the two statements give the same output.

Comment: Why not just use `urldecode()` alone?

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference:

```
$a = rawurldecode("aaa+bbb");
$b = rawurldecode(urlencode(urldecode("aaa+bbb")));
var_dump($a, $b);
```

> ```
> string(7) "aaa+bbb"
> string(7) "aaa+bbb"
> ```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/FrpbZ))

There *is* a difference though if you try the character that is not common to both encodings*:

```
$a = rawurldecode("aaa%20bbb");
$b = rawurldecode(urlencode(urldecode("aaa%20bbb")));
var_dump($a, $b);
```

> ```
> string(7) "aaa bbb"
> string(7) "aaa+bbb"
> ```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/M3R4v))

(*) As per the docs, [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/rawurlencode) implements RFC 3986 while [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode) implements application/x-www-form-urlencoded:

> This [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] differs from the RFC 3986
>   encoding [...] in that for historical reasons, spaces are encoded as
>   plus (+) signs.

Answer (score 0):

you don't get "aaa bbb" with `rawurldecode("aaa+bbb")` you get "aaa+bbb" (did you mean `urldecode("aaa+bbb")`?)

```
echo rawurldecode("aaa+bbb") . "<br>\n";
```

aaa+bbb

```
echo urldecode("aaa+bbb"). "<br>\n";
echo urlencode(urldecode("aaa+bbb")). "<br>\n";
echo rawurldecode(urlencode(urldecode("aaa+bbb"))). "<br>\n";
```

aaa bbb

aaa+bbb

aaa+bbb

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, it is actually correct. The difference between urldecode() and rawurldecode() is how the '+' character is handled in query strings. This answer correctly points out that rawurldecode() prints the plus sign per RFC3986 requirements. (urldecode(0 follows the RFC1866 spec and allows pluses to be decoded as spaces in the query part of the URL only)

Comment: @BitByteDog of course it's correct, but this is SO - basically the sand kicking corner of the universe